# How to configure Cisco AnyConnect (VPN client) on MacOS not to use port 80?

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

In response to [this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99068/rogue-process-occupying-port-80), I have determined that it is the Cisco AnyConnect (VPN client) that is hijacking my port 80.  I am looking to find out whether it is possible to reconfigure the VPN client to use a different port. I also would appreciate an explanation why `lsof` does not properly identify the causing process.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco Anyconnect can route all of it's traffic through Cisco servers.  They check all traffic for bad sites/reputation and all that.  It does all this on Port 80.  If you do a Google search and the results come back with little green marks by them showing they are ok, that's how you are setup.  I put it in at our bank.  There might be a way to defeat it, but normal ways like stunnel/Pytunnel probably won't work.  It might be very difficult.  Anyconnect probably wants a certificate, so you can't hijack the whole thing.  I wish I was more help.  We tell our employees "buy your own computer if you don't want Big Brother watching".  Maybe you could boot from an external drive running another OS?
- Joe